# Use non-specification attribute in React JSX? Such as ng-href

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting familiar with React and thinking of gradually moving my Angular app over to it. For now, I have one react component on my site. However, I need it to have an element with the `ui-href` attribute in my React component. I tried just putting it in as a string, like so:

```
<a { "ui-href='" + this.props.stateLink + "'" } >...</a>
```

But no joy, it says an error about unexpected string.

I also read you can prefix custom attributes with `data-` to make the make them work, and that's true, but it keeps the `data-` attached, e.g. `data-ui-href` is the actual final attribute it creates.

Any known workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I think the unexpected string error is occurring because you are mixing Angular & React syntax. Try this instead:

```
<a data-ui-href={this.props.stateLink} >...</a>
```

It does keep the `data-` prefix in the attribute though. Not sure what the workaround for that is.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple potential workarounds in this thread: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/140 There isn't a great solution, though.

Answer (score 0):

It's been in the works to get this a part of React, but it's not there yet.  Here is the original issue.  https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/140

A workaround for now is to add the attribute outside of what React does.  In `componentDidMount` for instance.

```
var Hello = React.createClass({

    componentDidMount: function() {
      React.findDOMNode(this.refs.link).setAttribute('ui-href', 'value');
    },

    render: function() {
        return <div>
          <a ref="link">Something</a>
        </div>;
    }
});
```

http://jsbin.com/cuzebuxuci/1/edit?html,js,output